# Let K $\in \mathbb R$ and let c be the constant sequence given by $c_n = K$. Prove that c converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Let K $\in \mathbb R$ and let c be the constant sequence given by $c_n = K$. Prove that c converges.

I don't know where to start this proof. All I know is the definition of convergence, which is, For a sequence x of real numbers and a real number L, we say x has limit L(or x converges to L) iff for every $\epsilon$ > 0 there exists a natural number N such that if n>N, then |$x_n - L$| < $\epsilon$.

($\forall > \epsilon$)($∃N \in \mathbb N$)($\forall n \in \mathbb N$)($n>N$ $\implies |x_n - L| < \epsilon$)

In this question my L is the K. and my $x_n$ is $c_n$ in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon >0$ be arbitrary. Then we have 
$$ |c_n - K | = |K-K|=0 < \varepsilon$$
for all $n\in \mathbf N$. This shows $c_n \to K$.

In this special case there is *no* number $N(\varepsilon)\in \mathbf N$ needed, such that $|c_n - K | < \varepsilon$ holds for all $n\geq N(\varepsilon)$ because this inequality is always fulfilled.

Comment: Ah makes sense. It was straight in front of me. Thanks

Comment: A simpler way to say that is that we can take $N(\epsilon)=1$.